# Storing a movie in the database-mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to store a movie into the database  using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO `tsd`.`movielist` (`Movie`,`Actor`,`Genre`,`Year`,`Video`) VALUES ('Captain America','Gerard Butler, Aaron Eckhart, Morgan Freeman', 'Action,Thriller,'2014',LOAD_FILE("C:\\Users\\LAVISH JAIN\Desktop\\Captain America The Winter Soldier (2014).mp4"));
```

The query works fine but when i try to retrieve it using:

```
select video from movielist;
```

I am getting NULL value as output.Is this correct?

Comment: Have you tried specifying what video you are 'selecting' from 'movielist' ?

Comment: I sense an error.  One of your strings is missing a single quote `'Action,Thriller`

Comment: Does your SQL client actually support displaying a video as port of the result set? Most SQL clients don't display BLOB data at all. And those that do usually only display images.

Comment: Do you have a good insurance against denormalization? just saying...

Comment: Are you sure the update actually worked? You're missing a single quote as DJ Burb pointed out. There is nothing wrong with your query at all, assuming data is there it will work.